# CheckBoxes In ListBox Make Scrolling Lag

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have been working on a small view in WPF that contains a few `Buttons` and a `ListBox` whose items have a template that contains a `CheckBox` and a `ContentPresenter`. When I start scrolling in `ListBox` the `ScrollBar` moves up and down laggy. It is kind of a performance issue and I think it is because of the `CheckBoxes`. I think the `CheckBoxes` have some kind of rendering animation that takes few milliseconds to fade in the tick and those run sync, hence the lag appears.

I could be wrong and maybe it's something else causing this problem. Futhermore just as a sidenote since it might matter to you guys I am running the application in Windows 7 on an Intel i5.

When I leave the `CheckBoxs` away from the template it all runs very smooth.

What do you guys suggest me to do?

I don't know how to disable that animation and I don't want that laggy behavour.

**EDIT: I have 5000 items in my ListBox**

Here is my XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Checked}"/>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Text}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This is my ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.Source = new ObservableCollection<ListItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            this.Source.Add(new ListItem(){ Text = "test" + i, Checked = true });
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ListItem> Source
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class ListItem
{
    public bool Checked
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

This is my MainWindow.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try use `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"` to improve performance during scrolling. In the extreme case try use `ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"` for deferred scrolling. For more info see: [link1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716876.aspx) and [link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879.aspx). Animation of `CheckBox` is probably nothing to do with.

Comment: @Anatoliy Post your comment as answer and I will mark it. Recycling did help a little bit, thanks for that advice. IsDefScrolling is not really what I am looking for but I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"` to improve performance during scrolling. In the extreme case try use `ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"` for deferred scrolling. For more information see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716876.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879.aspx

**Note:** You can try to run this code under other operating systems, such as: *Windows XP*. I have a feeling that on Windows 7 optimization WPF rendering implemented differently than XP. Because some code normally goes to XP, but by Seven brakes (but maybe I'm wrong).

P.S. I found nice [article](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/d/b/2db72dcf-5ae0-445f-b709-7f34437d8b21/Scrolling_in_WPF.doc&ei=PRvEUZn3EafU4QS6wIH4AQ&usg=AFQjCNERegTHaGdwifeSKIvYkljK62UNnw&sig2=uToovI-TWt_dq26vJPCe7g&bvm=bv.48293060,d.bGE) - "Improving Scrolling Performance in WPF. Author: Cedric Dussud". It may be useful.